# Tree structure not building as expected

Tags: javascript, node.js, data-structures, tree, fs

I'm trying to write a function to create a tree from a given starting directory. In other words, I choose a directory, and then the function maps absolutely everything in that particular directory. I've never done anything like this before, but I'm close to the expected output. However, I'm not sure where I'm going wrong.

## Starting Directory

```
> Test Root
    > 1a
    > 1b
        > 2a
        > 2b
        > 2c
    > 1c
        > 2a
    > 1d
        > 2a
        > 2b
    > testfile.txt
```

## Output

The first level is good to go. The second level is almost good to go, but for some reason it's duplicating the `parent` property and creating an additional nested object. It's also always inserting the `type` property. I've tried removing properties in the `constructor`, but that output is just as bewildering.

```
{
  "parent": null,
  "path": "C:\\Users\\Anthony\\Desktop\\Test Root",
  "name": "Test Root",
  "kids": [
    {
      "parent": {
        "parent": "C:\\Users\\Anthony\\Desktop\\Test Root",
        "path": "C:\\Users\\Anthony\\Desktop\\Test Root\\1a",
        "name": "1a",
        "kids": []
      },
      "type": "fileType"
    },
    {
      "parent": {
        "parent": "C:\\Users\\Anthony\\Desktop\\Test Root",
        "path": "C:\\Users\\Anthony\\Desktop\\Test Root\\1b",
        "name": "1b",
        "kids": [
          {
            "parent": {
              "parent": "C:\\Users\\Anthony\\Desktop\\Test Root\\1b",
              "path": "C:\\Users\\Anthony\\Desktop\\Test Root\\1b\\2a",
              "name": "2a",
              "kids": []
            },
            "type": "fileType"
          },
          {
            "parent": {
              "parent": "C:\\Users\\Anthony\\Desktop\\Test Root\\1b",
              "path": "C:\\Users\\Anthony\\Desktop\\Test Root\\1b\\2b",
              "name": "2b",
              "kids": []
            },
            "type": "fileType"
          },
          {
            "parent": {
              "parent": "C:\\Users\\Anthony\\Desktop\\Test Root\\1b",
              "path": "C:\\Users\\Anthony\\Desktop\\Test Root\\1b\\2c",
              "name": "2c",
              "kids": []
            },
            "type": "fileType"
          }
        ]
      },
      "type": "fileType"
    },
    {
      "parent": {
        "parent": "C:\\Users\\Anthony\\Desktop\\Test Root",
        "path": "C:\\Users\\Anthony\\Desktop\\Test Root\\1c",
        "name": "1c",
        "kids": [
          {
            "parent": {
              "parent": "C:\\Users\\Anthony\\Desktop\\Test Root\\1c",
              "path": "C:\\Users\\Anthony\\Desktop\\Test Root\\1c\\2a",
              "name": "2a",
              "kids": []
            },
            "type": "fileType"
          }
        ]
      },
      "type": "fileType"
    },
    {
      "parent": {
        "parent": "C:\\Users\\Anthony\\Desktop\\Test Root",
        "path": "C:\\Users\\Anthony\\Desktop\\Test Root\\1d",
        "name": "1d",
        "kids": [
          {
            "parent": {
              "parent": "C:\\Users\\Anthony\\Desktop\\Test Root\\1d",
              "path": "C:\\Users\\Anthony\\Desktop\\Test Root\\1d\\2a",
              "name": "2a",
              "kids": []
            },
            "type": "fileType"
          },
          {
            "parent": {
              "parent": "C:\\Users\\Anthony\\Desktop\\Test Root\\1d",
              "path": "C:\\Users\\Anthony\\Desktop\\Test Root\\1d\\2b",
              "name": "2b",
              "kids": []
            },
            "type": "fileType"
          }
        ]
      },
      "type": "fileType"
    },
    {
      "parent": {
        "parent": "C:\\Users\\Anthony\\Desktop\\Test Root",
        "path": "C:\\Users\\Anthony\\Desktop\\Test Root\\testfile.txt",
        "name": "testfile.txt",
        "type": "fileType"
      },
      "type": "fileType"
    }
  ]
}
```

## Function

```
async function createTree(root){
  const
    Node = class {
      constructor(parent, path, name, fifo){
        this.parent = parent
        this.path = path
        this.name = name
        fifo ? this.kids = [] : this.type = 'fileType'
      }
      addChild(parent, path, name, fifo){
        this.kids.push(new Node(parent, path, name, fifo))
      }
    },
    traverse = async function(node, path){
      const childPaths = await fsp.readdir(path)
      for (const childPath of childPaths){
        const
          name = childPath,
          stats = await fsp.stat(join(path, childPath))
        let
          fifo

        if (stats.isDirectory()) fifo = 1
        else if (stats.isFile()) fifo = 0

        const
          childNode = new Node(path, join(path, childPath), name, fifo)

        node.addChild(childNode)

        traverse(childNode, join(path, childPath))
      }
    },
    rootName = root.slice(-1) === '\\' ? root.slice(0,1) : root.slice(root.lastIndexOf('\\')+1),
    tree = new Node(null, root, rootName, 1)

    traverse(tree, root)

    setTimeout(function(){
      console.log(JSON.stringify(tree, null, 2))
    }, 2500)
}
```

I just realized my asynchronous functions aren't returning anything. I'm going to have to look over all of this tomorrow.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you are passing in only the first argument to your `addChild` function here.

The `addChild` function expects 4 arguments to be provided. However:

```
node.addChild(childNode)

// is approximately equivalent to:

addChild ( Node {...}, undefined, undefined, undefined)
```

You should be calling the function like this:

```
node.addChild(childNode.path, childNode.path, childNode.name, childNode.fifo)
```

---

You're on the right path logically, approaching a nicely recursive solution, but I think the class is a bit overkill and far too object-oriented for a functional problem such as this. Here's a quick example of a more functional version which should give you the result you expect:

```
const nodePath = require('path');
const fs = require('fs');

/**
 * Supply an `fs` function and it will turn it into a promisified version
 * @param {Function} fn The function to promisify. This means you do not 
 * need the `fsp` library.
 */
function promisify (fn) {
  return (...args) => new Promise((resolve, reject) => fn(...args, (err, data) => err ? reject(err) : resolve(data)));
};

// Create promisified versions of `fs.stat` and `fs.readdir`
const stat = promisify(fs.stat);
const readdir = promisify(fs.readdir);

function createDirectory (parent, path, name, kids) {
  return { parent, path, name, kids: kids || [] };
};

function createFile (parent, path, name) {
  return { parent, path, name, type: 'fileType' };
}

// The main recursive function.
async function createTree (parent, path) {
  let stats = await stat(path);

  if (stats.isDirectory()) {
    const children = await readdir(path);

    // Because each recursive call retruns a promise, we want to continue only when
    // all of them have resolved. So we use Promise.all for this.
    let child_nodes = await Promise.all(
      children.map(child => createTree(path, nodePath.join(path, child)))
    );

    // Create a directory node
    return createDirectory(parent, path, nodePath.basename(path), child_nodes);
  }

  // Create a file node
  return createFile(parent, path, nodePath.basename(path));
};


// Startup code, can use your own stuff here.
async function start () {
  let tree = await createTree(null, '/home/james/stackoverflow/58706769/Test Root');

  console.log(JSON.stringify(tree, null, 2));
}

start();
```

Running this file in Node, I get the following output:

```
{
  "parent": null,
  "path": "/home/james/stackoverflow/58706769/Test Root",
  "name": "Test Root",
  "kids": [
    {
      "parent": "/home/james/stackoverflow/58706769/Test Root",
      "path": "/home/james/stackoverflow/58706769/Test Root/1a",
      "name": "1a",
      "kids": []
    },
    {
      "parent": "/home/james/stackoverflow/58706769/Test Root",
      "path": "/home/james/stackoverflow/58706769/Test Root/1b",
      "name": "1b",
      "kids": [
        {
          "parent": "/home/james/stackoverflow/58706769/Test Root/1b",
          "path": "/home/james/stackoverflow/58706769/Test Root/1b/2a",
          "name": "2a",
          "kids": []
        },
        {
          "parent": "/home/james/stackoverflow/58706769/Test Root/1b",
          "path": "/home/james/stackoverflow/58706769/Test Root/1b/2b",
          "name": "2b",
          "kids": []
        },
        {
          "parent": "/home/james/stackoverflow/58706769/Test Root/1b",
          "path": "/home/james/stackoverflow/58706769/Test Root/1b/2c",
          "name": "2c",
          "kids": []
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "parent": "/home/james/stackoverflow/58706769/Test Root",
      "path": "/home/james/stackoverflow/58706769/Test Root/1c",
      "name": "1c",
      "kids": [
        {
          "parent": "/home/james/stackoverflow/58706769/Test Root/1c",
          "path": "/home/james/stackoverflow/58706769/Test Root/1c/2a",
          "name": "2a",
          "kids": []
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "parent": "/home/james/stackoverflow/58706769/Test Root",
      "path": "/home/james/stackoverflow/58706769/Test Root/1d",
      "name": "1d",
      "kids": [
        {
          "parent": "/home/james/stackoverflow/58706769/Test Root/1d",
          "path": "/home/james/stackoverflow/58706769/Test Root/1d/2a",
          "name": "2a",
          "kids": []
        },
        {
          "parent": "/home/james/stackoverflow/58706769/Test Root/1d",
          "path": "/home/james/stackoverflow/58706769/Test Root/1d/2b",
          "name": "2b",
          "kids": []
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "parent": "/home/james/stackoverflow/58706769/Test Root",
      "path": "/home/james/stackoverflow/58706769/Test Root/testfile.txt",
      "name": "testfile.txt",
      "type": "fileType"
    }
  ]
}
```

Comment: that def fixed a large part of it. for some reason now its not crawling/mapping the 3rd and last level children. ill have to thoroughly look over my code again tomorrow. hopefully the fresh mind will help

Comment: im pretty sure it has something to do with how im passing the `parentNode` forward. anyways, im off. thanks for your help. appreciate it!!

Comment: just noticed you edited your answer. ill take a look as soon as i get up tomo morn

Comment: didnt get around to it today. will be doing it tomorrow

Comment: man i dont know why i struggle to write this code in such a succinct and clear manner like yourself. im fairly new to all of this stuff (i.e. node, JSON, objects, promises, etc), but it doesnt seem complicated when i look at other peoples code, yet i still struggle to wrap my head around it all at once.

Comment: is there any particular reason you created your own `promisify` function as opposed to using `fs.promises`?

Comment: also, im so confused by `return { param, param, param... }`. the properties assume the parameter name as the key, and the argument as the value?

Comment: and u cant use arrow expressions to return an object like that eh? interesting. ive learned so much from this :)

Comment: Practice makes perfect. I've written code to walk a file tree countless times, so I can do it kind of off the top of my head now. I could'nt get the `fsp` lib working, and didn't really bother trying because promisifying node callbacks is pretty easy, that's about it. Yes `return { param1, param2 }` is equivalent to `return { param1: param1, param2: param2 }`. Not sure what you're asking about arrow functions, they can return objects, like this: `(param1, param2) => ({ param1, param2 })`. You just have to wrap them in parenthesis or us explicit return instead.

Comment: ya i wasnt really asking anything, just stating that i had tried `(p1, p2...) => {{p1, p2...}}` which didnt work. i def just need to write more code that involves this stuff. anyways, thanks so much for all your help man!!

Comment: omg bro i finally wrote a promisified, recursive function (that builds out the JSON as HTML) that works!!! all on my own whoop whoop. if youd like to critique the code and possibly offer improvements thereto, [the codereview question is here](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/q/232037/108405)